# Trouble with simple Mips function

Tags: mips, mips32

Attempting to write a Mips function with parameters $a0 - (addr) str, $a1 - (int) n that returns the addr of the string that's the last Length - n of the input str.

However I'm getting unwanted results and fear an infinite loop or logical   errror. This is what I've got so far...

.globl suffix

```
 suffix:
 li $t0, 0  #sets $t0 to 0
 jal length #length is another function that sets $v0 to the length of the 
         input string, pretty sure it works
 li  $t1, 0
 add $t1, $t1, $v0
 sub $t1, $t1, $a1  
 lb $v0, ($a0)  
 other_loop:
 beq  $t1, $t0, other_exit
 sb   $v0, ($a0)
 addi $t0, $t0, 1
 addi $a0, $a0, 1
 j other_loop

other_exit:
 jr $ra
```

I'm worried I'm incorrectly calling my Length function(which sets $v0 to the length of the input str $va0
-Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're clobbering `$ra`.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I haven't heard that before. It might be the line that branches.

Comment: When you `jal somewhere`, you expect `jr $ra` to return you whence you came (that't the point of calling a function after all). How does `jr $ra` know where to return to? Well, it's `$ra`, aka `r31`, which holds the **r**eturn **a**ddress. But, since this is a *register*, issuing the next `jal` before a `jr $ra` overwrites the contents of the register.